# Quantum fourier transformation Unitary proof.

Tags: proof-verification, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces, quantum-mechanics

I've found a bunch of these proofs online but I am having trouble understanding how the norm of the column/row is 1.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $i=j$ you get
$$FT_N \cdot FT_N = \frac1N \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \omega^{ik - ik} = \frac1N \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} 1 = 1$$
Note that $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z_N}$ is the same as $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}$. This is due to the definition of $\omega$ (actually dependent on $N$):
$$\omega = e^{\frac{2\pi i}N}$$
So that $\omega^k = e^{\frac{2\pi ik}N}$ and $\bar\omega = \omega^{-1}$ so $\omega^i \bar\omega^j = \omega^{i-j}$

Comment: Can you please explain the first equality. FTN*FTN=

Comment: @AliceAndBob Well, that's directly taken from the first line (Where proof is given that it's orthogonal), just plugged $i=j$ in.

Comment: I believe that's where I'm lost. How does the first equality happen?

Comment: @AliceAndBob Note the special property $\bar\omega = \omega^{-1}$